# On Git Push to one server, also pull the pushed files using ftp?

Tags: ftp, gitlab

Sorry if the title is confusing...
So, we have 2 servers. A Root Server for internal Stuff (GitLab, etc) and one managed server where we don't have SSH. Just Plesk and FTP.

So basically, I git push my commits to the root server running gitlab. After the push is complete I also want that the entire repo or new commits are getting pulled to the managed plesk-server.

Is this possible?
Also, one thing worth to mention is that plesk creates subfolders for every domain, so it should be possible to specific a folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are using the most recent version of gitlab with its [ci-runner](https://about.gitlab.com/gitlab-ci/), you could trigger a job where you can use [lftp](http://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/setup-lftp-command-line-ftp/) to upload the latest working copy of the repo to your Plesk server. Avoid using plain FTP, use FTP over SSL

Here are some links for GitLab and CI-Runner

[Install a GitLab CE Omnibus package](https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/)

[The TL;DR version of how GitLab CI works](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/ci/quick_start/README.html)

You would hardly get away with something simpler or better documented, this doesn't require a lot of Linux background, very few command line action, mainly editing text files

Hope this helps

Comment: I have actually done this in production, and can confirm that it works quite well.

Comment: Is there any good tutorial on this maybe? I am not really that much experienced with linux.

Comment: I just edited/updated the original answer with a couple of useful links to thorough documentation about gitlab and ci-runner

Comment: This is the best answer so far, but it would be better if it included a .gitlab-ci.yml example rather than just pointing at links.  This post includes an example if you're up for updating your answer: http://blog.kay-strobach.de/index.php/2016/02/11/how-to-deploy-your-static-website-easily-with-gitlab/

Answer (score 2):

You should look into [git hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).

Git hooks allow you to fire off a script after a specific command. It's very flexible. So, for example, you could have a shell script that triggers on a git push command to also upload that copy to the FTP server.

Also, I haven't looked into [git-ftp](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp), but it seems like it could help you to upload the changed files to an FTP server.

Comment: Git Hooks are only useable with the Enterprise version of Gitlab right? So that's maybe not an option right now. Git-ftp looks nice, but am I right that it runs on the clients side? As I am running windows (and a GUI for Git)

Comment: Doing git hooks through the web interface is a Gitlab enterprise feature, but if you have shell access to the Gitlab server, you can add git hooks through the CLI: http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/hooks/custom_hooks.html 

Similarly, if you have control over the Gitlab box, you can use git-ftp on it, too, and push the files from the Gitlab repo from the CLI. 

All that said, kamihack's answer seems simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can do both actions locally. You can push to your internal server and deploy through FTP to your other server from your own computer.

You can use [PHPloy](https://github.com/banago/PHPloy) to deploy the changes through FTP.

You can combine the actions by putting the `phploy` command in a `post-commit` hook.

*Disclaimer: I've developed PHPloy.*

Comment: Sounds interesting. I'm currently doing exactly that using GoodSync. I will absolutely try your tool out.